# Which tools integrate Leica zeno 5 gps handhelds into ArcGIS?

Tags: gps

What other software can I use with my Zeno 5 gps handheld device from Leica geosystems except the one they offer that integrates with ArcGIS desktop?

They suggested the 'Zeno office' and the 'Zeno field' or this software http://www.microsurvey.com/products/fieldgenius/price2007-canada.htm and the 'Zeno connect'.

It wasn't clear on the website that you have to buy this extra software so that the zeno 5 gps device will function properly. From my experience I know that when you buy a gps handheld device you don't need to buy extra software to display your position, the satellites, your accuracy, your lat and lon in a user interface. Is there a less expensive alternative software I can purchase and install in this device?

Answer (score 1):

One reliable option we have been using for 8 years is Starpal's HGIS now for WEH6.5 - also has a version that runs on PCs. Edits shapefiles and MIF/MID pairs and supports compressed image formats.